# Confused about how to read integer from mixed character from a file in C

Tags: c

Well, I have a file containing this:

`1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14 
A|B 
1`

and I have this (a bit) complicated structure in a C program

```
typedef struct{
    ArrInt states;
    Word symbol;
    int initState;
}Sym;

typedef struct{
   char arr[ARRAY_SIZE];
   int length;
   boolean EOW;
}Word;

typedef struct{
   int Tab[ARRAY_SIZE];
   int length;
}ArrInt;

Sym SymVar;
```

What I want to do is as follow:

1. Read the first line as integer, separated by '|',  and store them as `SymVar.states`,as example `Symvar.states[0]` contains `1`, `Symvar.states[1]` contains `2`, and so on. The reading will stop if it encounters `return` character;
2. Read the second line as character, separated by '|', and store them as `SymVar.symbol`, e.g. `SymVar.states[0]` contains `A` and `SymVar.states[1]` contains `B`. The reading will stop if it encounters `return` character;
3. Read the third line as integer, and store it as `SymVar.initState`.

I've tried many approach, but none of them were successful. Here is a snippet of my latest approach:

```
//this code has failed
Word WFinalState; 
Word WStates;
Word Winit;

AdvAcqWord(&WStates, fileSymbol);
AdvAcqWord(&(SymVar.symbol), fileSymbol);
AdvAcqWord(&Winit, fileSymbol);

ConvertToInt(WStates, &(SymVar.states));
```

I know I've done wrong. What `AdvAcqWord` does is reading the file character by character, ignore it if it is a whitespace, then create a `word` from it. ConvertToInt is just converting element in `word` to integer, then store them to an `ArrInt`

```
void ConvertToInt(Word W, ArrInt *Tab)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i<W.length; i++);
    (*Tab).Tab[i] = strtoimax((*W.tab[i]), NULL, 10) ;
(*Tab).length = W.length;
}

void AdvAcqWord(Word *W, FILE *fin)
{
boolean loopIgnore = true;
//Ignoring whiteSpace,
while (loopIgnore){
    Ignore_Blank(fin);
    if (isspace(CC))
        loopIgnore = true;
    else loopIgnore = false;
    }

//Marking end of a word
if ((CC == mark) || (CC == '/'))
    (*W).EOW = true;
else{
    (*W).EOW = false;
    CreateWord(W, fin);
    }
}
```

`CreateWord` is just a procedure to construct a new `word` `W` from a file input `fin`.

I've been thinking of hours but I couldn't find a solution yet. I'm a beginner to C. Any help will be very appreciated. If any solution with a clear explanation exist before, please link me to it. I need a very clear explanation.

Regards

Comment: You need to read up on tokenising and state machines. Basically you want a state machine to read  the characters one at a time and based on the current and the next character you build up tokens.

Comment: A few hints... Check out the functions: strchr and atoi. Another really useful function for you is strtok, but its use might not be that intuitive. You might also want to read up on null-terminated strings which eliminates the need to store the length of a string in a struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a very basic example

Init struct with `0` using `memset`

Read the file line with `fgets`

parse the first line with `strol` check if the separator char is a `|`

Then parse char by char doing the same check

Finally a basic `atoi` for last int

Some remark try to name with consistence you use `arr` and `Tab`

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <errno.h> 

#define ARRAY_SIZE 64 

typedef struct { 
   char arr[ARRAY_SIZE]; 
   int length; 
} Word; 

typedef struct{ 
   int Tab[ARRAY_SIZE]; 
   int length; 
} ArrInt; 

typedef struct { 
    ArrInt states; 
    Word symbol; 
    int initState; 
} Sym;  

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    FILE *f; 
    char buf[BUFSIZ]; 
    char *p; 
    Sym var; 

    memset(&var, 0, sizeof(var)); 

    if (argc < 2) { 
        return -1; 
    }   

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r"); 
    if (!f) { 
        printf("fopen failed, errno = %d\n", errno); 
        return errno; 
    } 
    /* parse int */ 
    p = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f); 
    if (!p) 
        return ferror(f); 

    while (p) { 
        var.states.Tab[var.states.length++] = strtol(p, &p, 10); 
        if (*p == '\n') 
            break; 
        if (*p++ != '|') { 
            fprintf(stderr, "Bad format"); 
            return -1; 
        } 
    } 
    /* parse char */ 
    p = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f); 
    if (!p) 
        return 1; 

    while (p) { 
        var.symbol.arr[var.symbol.length++] = *p++; 
        if (*p == '\n') 
            break; 
        if (*p++ != '|') { 
            fprintf(stderr, "Bad format"); 
            return -1; 
        } 
    } 
    /* parse char */ 
    p = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f); 
    if (!p) 
        return 1; 
    var.initState = atoi(p); 

    return 0; 

}
```

(gdb) p var
$2 = {states = {Tab = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0 }, length = 14}, symbol = {arr = "AB", '\000' , length = 2}, initState = 1}

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert int from a char just use

```
int num;
char ch;
num = ch - 48;
```

or

```
num = ch -'0';
```

Comment: and check if `ch > '9'` or `ch < '0'` to trigger an error